# 2 state converter, from -24VDC [ON] - +5VDC [OFF] to 5VDC [ON] - 0VDC [OFF]

Tags: voltage, power, converter, logic-level

So as the header says, I would like to take a 2 state signal (ON/OFF) where the on state is -24VDC and it's off state is +5VDC and make that/convert to a 0-5VDC 2 state signal, where 0 is the corresponding off state and +5VDC is the corresponding on state.  Need some direction/help with this one, thanks.

Comment: Low frequency or high frequency?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I was going to ask the same question about the current.

Comment: not really a  frequency, 2 states...on and off...sometimes it's on...sometimes it's off, more so a trigger thing I suppose..so lets say very, very low frequency,

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSJTs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Opto-isolator level shifter.*

Opto isolators are great for this kind of application as there is no direct connection between each circuit.

- With SW1 open D1 is off and Q1 is open circuit. '5 V logic' output is at 0 V.
- With SW1 closed D1 turns on and Q1 pulls the output line to +5 V.

Comment: aye, I was kinda thinking along that line, but didn't quite have it pieced together, thanks.

Comment: @transistor Small suggestion: I would keep the upper left node tied to GND (like prior to your edit) and remove the switch, naming the lower left node _original logic_ or _24V logic_ (so it's consistent with the _5V logic tag_). When the signal of the lower left node goes to 5V, it cuts off; when it is -24V it is on.

Comment: Yes, I started with R1 connected to GND but then wondered if that was really available. The other aspect was that D1 would be reverse biased when input is +5. I know the LED should survive but it seems wrong. @lordentropy: Can you explain the source of your rather unusual -24 to +5 logic? I can then give a better schematic.

Comment: At the moment no, the source is some other piece of electronics that is commercial, but that's all I know unfortunately.

Comment: any specific/favorite transistor optocouplers you recommend?

Comment: No. Pretty much any basic opto-transistor type should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially do this simply with a 5V Zener diode regulator and an inverter:

[image: Regulator]

<sup>(Click picture to go to simulation)</sup>

However, whether or not that works will depend on the impedance of the source and what frequency you are planning on running at.

Comment: What simulator are you using out of curiosity?

Comment: @lordentropy it's an online Java simulator (the falstad one). If you click on the image it will load it for you.